# Why is the answer to this 10?

Tags: javascript

I know the outcome of this is 10:

```
var es = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  es[i] = function () {
    console.log(i);
  };
}
es[6]();
```

Any number of es[0] - es[9] is still 10. but why?

Comment: `i` only exists once and can only keep 1 value. After all the `i++`, it'll be `10`.

Answer (score 5):

Because after the loop `i` is `10`. The function prints the reference of `i`.

Answer (score 3):

There is only integer object created.  Those `console.log(i)` are all referring to the same object in memory.  The value of `i` - the only `i` - is of course 10 at the end of the loop.

Note the line `console.log(i)` creates a closure, which in particular means it's not creating a new reference to the variable referred to by `i`. It's the same reference.

A good way to do this analysis is to keep tracking of the number of times in your code a new actual variable is created.  If you've programmed in C or C++ or wherever, you know that an integer takes 4 or 8 bytes of memory.  The line `for(var i = 0;` can be thought of as creating one object.  Just one.  Nothing inside of the function creates another object, since closures don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

That's because by the time you execute `console.log(i)`, `i` has changed as the loop finished.

More precisely, the `for` loop stops when the condition `i < 10` is false, that is when `i` is `10`. What you have after that is 10 **identical** functions, all using the same, externally defined variable `i`.

You can fix it using this classical closure trick :

```
var es = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   (function(j){
     es[j] = function () {
       console.log(j);
     };
   })(i);
}
es[6]();
```

What this code does is create a new variable, `j`, whose scope is the anonymous function call. This is a way to save the value `i` has when the function is called (that is *during* the loop instead of when `es[6]` is called).

Comment: Hum, why the downvote ? I'm the only one here to answer with working code...

Comment: Yes, wyh? This answer not only correctly answers the question but also gives valid code example for intended behaviour of asker.

Comment: Only improvement I would make is to change the parameter name from `i` to avoid confusion. Otherwise looks good to me.

Comment: Why wouldn't the answer be 9 though?  Because its i < 10.  Also, I dont understand why if it's in a for loop it only prints once.  Can you explain these things?

Comment: The loop stops when i<10 isn't true anymore. It means that at just after the loop, i is 10. Your for loop doesn't print the numbers : it creates functions (all identical), and you call only one of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are referring to `i` and after the loop it is `10`i.e, when you are executing console.log(i). The value of i has changed to 10.