# AngularJS : assign asynchronous data to an array element in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm trying to assign array elements in a for loop with asynchronous results of a call to a `ngResource` action.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < projs.length; i++) {
    $scope.projets[i].redacteur = new Object(); // the Object where the result will be stored
    var param = new Object();
    param.email = projs[i].redacteurEmail;
    Agent.read(param, function(data) {
        $scope.projets[i].redacteur = data;
    });


}
```

The problem is : when the callback function is executed (when the data is received), `i` is out of bounds (it passed the last `i++`). Then the data received is assigned to a nonexistent object.

Any idea of a solution to this issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript infamous Loop problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem)

Comment: and [Problem with loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549911/problem-with-loop)

Comment: and [Weird value for counter variable in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317495/weird-value-for-counter-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: also [Why is the answer to this 10?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622522/why-is-the-answer-to-this-10)

Comment: and this one [How to generate event handlers with loop in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6487366/1331430)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue by putting the call to the callback function in a closure. With my example, it looks like that :

```
for (var i = 0; i < projs.length; i++) {
    $scope.projets[i].redacteur = new Object(); // the Object where the result will be stored
    var param = new Object();
    param.email = projs[i].redacteurEmail;
    (function(i) {
        Agent.read(param, function(data) {
            $scope.projets[i].redacteur = data;
        });
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: Trop fort !! You saved my skin here ! I now need to read about javascript closures.

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't understand why I had the same behavior. Using a function solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and I solved it by using 
Promises. The basic idea is that I send the index of the array as a parameter to my asynchronous request callback, and then I can handle it when the response arrives.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your issue correctly, I believe this may work.

```
myData = Agent.read(param, function() {
    $scope.projets[i].redacteur = myData;
});
```

This is the approach I have used.  I'm still new to Angular, but my understanding is that myData becomes a deferred promise.  As a deferred promise it must be resolved prior to use. Please, someone who has more experience Angular and deferred promises chime in.